# How to write a code for Jcryption in JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, jcryption

I am testing some application, where are doing Jcryption on client side and pass the encrypted value in subsequent request. I'm doing correlation to take the keys and planning to send other values[which they captured in client side] from csv data set config, but not sure how to write a code to do the Jcryption in jmeter. Can some one help me out?

I don't know how to write jcryption code in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

There is [jCryption for Java](http://www.michalfranc.com/articles/jcryption.html) class which you use in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

You may also find [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) article useful.